# previous props not getting in component will receive props function in react

Tags: reactjs

i try to compare the prev props and new props and if it is not same update the state.
but i am getting prev props as empty in every time

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (props, prevProps) => {

     if (
        props.data.length > 0 &&  
        props.data !== prevProps.data 
    ) { 
        
      this.setState({
        data: props.data
      }); 
    }
}
```

when props changed ,I need to compare old and new props , if old and new props are not same need to update the state.

Comment: You probably won’t like the direction I take, but why do you need to store this prop as state? Its already a prop, can’t you just use it and let it re-render when a new value is passed as a prop? Storing props as state in React doesn’t often make a lot of sense.

Comment: With hooks you only need to use useEffect

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use React Hook. It is powerful library to handle state and props in previous and current value.

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-get-previous-props-state-with-react-hooks/

BR

Answer (score -1):

read doc about [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). This method provide only 1 argument - `nextProps`

Answer (score -1):

To answer your original question, componentWillReceiveProps has been deprecated for a while. Ideally you use https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops to achieve what you are doing here. Although this should be used sparingly, I still have a hard time understanding why you would duplicate the state like this.

You could also do componentDidUpdate(prevProps), and then use this.props for the current value.

I haven’t used class based components for a while. I use Hooks now.